# Data image(base64) to normal url or blob url

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, base64, blob, ionic4

So what i am trying to achieve is. Users can choose between taking a picture from camera and upload a picture but whenever they upload the picture the picture will be a 'data:image/jpeg;base64' and i've tried making the data image a blob but my blob returns an object and not a url string back so how do i do this? the best way what i have now is:

```
 this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
        this.myphoto = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
        this.b64toBlob(this.myphoto, 'image/jpeg', 512);
    }, (err) => {
        // Handle error
    });
```

the code for the camera

and the base64 converter to blob

```
 b64toBlob(b64Data: string, contentType: string, sliceSize: number) {
    contentType = contentType || '';
    sliceSize = sliceSize || 512;

    var byteCharacters = atob(b64Data.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpeg|jpg);base64,/, ''));
    var byteArrays = [];

    for (var offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
        var slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);

        var byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
            byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
        }

        var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);

        byteArrays.push(byteArray);
    }
```

how can i make this a blob link or something that will be usefull to store images to database

Comment: Do you want to store the image/blob locally or in a remote db?
If locally, try the file plugin in ionic.

Comment: i want to store it into my database but do i have to safe it as base64 or how should i save the images? in blob? because if i convert them to a blob the blob is an object and not a blob url that i can click and see the image so what would you suggest because i have no idea

Comment: In this case, I think the easiest (not necessarily the most efficient) way would be to store the image as base64 string in your db. Then you can handle it like any other data url.